# Display fetch data in accordion React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm using an accordion list from native base, and all i'm displaying rightnow is:

```
const dataArray = [
  { title: "Desc", content: "n" },
  { title: "education1", content: "n" },
  { title: "education2", content: "n" },
  { title: "Price", content: 'n' },
  { title: "place", content: "n" },
 { title: "paiement", content: "n" }
];
...
 <Content padder>
          <Accordion dataArray={dataArray} expanded={0} />
        </Content>
```

so i fetched some data from a database and i want to diplay the content of every array inside the corresponding  accordion pad, here is the format of the data:

```
Array [
  Object {
    "code": false,
    "id": 10,
    "name": "medecin_mediclic",
    "presentation": false,
    "profession": "Medecin",
    "specialite": "Généraliste",
  },
  Object {
    "education": Array [],
  },
  Object {
    "education": Array [],
  },
  Object {
    "price": Array [],
  },
  Object {
    "place": Array [],
  },
  Object {
    "paiement": Array [],
  },
]
```

for example, in my accordion list first pad is "Desc" should contain:
   "medecin_mediclic",
    false,
    "Medecin",
     "Généraliste",
and so on.if the array is null then nothing comes out
anyone have any idea how to do it?

Comment: could you explain your question a bit more?

Comment: @SDushan i edited it , feel free to ask more questions